# How to get a simple Android (Studio) Proguard config working

Tags: android, proguard

Every project I've previously worked on where Proguard was specified it was eventually abandoned as enabling it caused so many problems it was unusable and an enormous drain on resources. But my current project really does require obfuscation to make reverse-engineering more difficult. As I'm using Android Studio and Gradle I enabled it in the build config:

```
    release {
        runProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
```

I then build a release build and see 292 warnings and build failure. Most are as follows and relate to libraries (Retrofit, Joda Time, Butterknife etc)

```
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
```

OK, so I assume it is optimising away portions of the libraries. So I tried adding lines like this to the proguard-rules.pro file (specified in the Gradle file and auto-created by Android Studio):

```
-keep class butterknife.internal.** { *; }
```

No difference. OK, so I'll try disabling ALL shrinking and optimising to hopefully only benefit from obfuscation (even if admittedly a little less obfuscation benefit). I added these line to the Proguard config file:

```
-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
```

I recompile, and absolutely nothing changes, I'm still left with 292 fairly meaningless compilation warnings. Now I'm really confused.

- How can I make 100% certain Proguard is actually reading my Proguard config file? Or is it using it but I've set an incorrect option?
- What can I add to the Proguard file to reduce its work to JUST obfuscation so I have a Proguard-enabled build config that works as a starting point (without breaking my app) and does not optimise away any code.

I would appreciate any help to assist in reducing my hatred of Proguard.

Answer (score 0):

put the following in your proguard config so that it wont mung up your butterknife library.

```
-keep class butterknife.** { *; }
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewInjector { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <methods>;
}
```

here is a github discussion link about the same issue, https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/pull/117#issuecomment-51292624

Comment: Your answer helps in that adding these lines affected the build, so I know the proguard config file is being used. But I don't want to fix each library one by one, I want to disable all the optimisations that remove code so Proguard only obfuscates the code. I have tried using the approach you mentioned (specifically --dontwarn which I wasn't using before) so adding lines like "-dontwarn okio.**" has allowed me to resolve the build warnings and create an APK which is great, but the APK crashes in a whole variety of ways it doesn't without Proguard. I need to stop Proguard deleting code.

Comment: Looking through the Proguard manual it looks like what I need is the ability to KEEP everything. I want to start from a position of it not removing any code, just optimising obfuscating, but I can't see how to keep all, it seems to require me to individually keep each class erroneously removed, but that is not straightforward.